# Excel VBA: Copy cell value in a table to a table on a different sheet with condition

Tags: vba, excel

I'll apologize in advance for the large scope of this question and any vagueness I might create. I'd like to create a macro that goes down a table and copy a cell value if a particular condition is met in a different column in that row to a table in another sheet.

Basically, if Condition equals X in column C in Table A, then copy Number from column B in Table A to column B in Table B. There are 2k+ rows. Column C in Table A is always empty or equals X, and column B in Table A is never empty until the end of the list. Column B in Table B is blank and the number of rows will be determined by the number of rows copied to it from Table A.

I'm sure this will require a loop, but being new to VBA, I'm not sure which loop type I need and how the  loop logic should look. I suspect a Do Until would be easiest since there are no blanks in Table A until the end of the list. My best guess so far:

```
Dim wsPAPS As Range
Dim wsPAVA As Range
Dim wsVNPN As Range
Dim wkATTR As Workbook

Set wkATTR = Workbooks("PARCEL_ATTR_MACRO-TEST.xlsm")
Set wsPAPS = Sheets("PARCEL_ATTR_BASE").Range("PARCELSTAT")
Set wsPAVA = Sheets("PARCEL_ATTR_BASE").Range("APO_VA_Properties_Vacant_Abandoned")
Set wsVNPN = Sheets("VA_NAME").Range("L1_PARCEL_NBR")

Do
    If wsPAVA = "Vacant/Abandoned" Then
        wsVNPN = wsPAPS
    End IF
Loop Until wsPAPS = ""
```

Note this code doesn't actually work; I'm told I have a Loop without a Do, not sure why.

I would be incredibly grateful for any help offered on this. Thanks, all!

**UPDATE** The intent with the Range variables is to attempt to make referencing specific columns easy, but I get an application-defined or object-defined error for them.

Comment: You need to use the Do while (condition) then at the end say "Loop"

http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps,

- Define the desitination worksheet/workbook by its range (cSheetName)
- Define the source worksheet/workbook by its range(cFileLocWS)
- Take row count for the operation to be performed can be upto 1 million rows.
- Add the loop not necessarily do while a simple "For" would do.

'Days Open for - Col:S

'Existing Logic ==$T$1-I(n)+1
'$T$1 - end of month date

```
lRowCount = Sheets(cSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
For rowIndex = 2 To lRowCount
    mDate = Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cMonthEndDate).Value
    strtDate = Sheets(cSheetName).Cells(rowIndex, "I").Value
    lResult = (mDate - strtDate) + 1
    Sheets(cSheetName).Cells(rowIndex, "S").Value = lResult
Next rowIndex
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Assuming the sheet names are: "TableA" and "TableB" and Column B always has some data.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim lr As Long, r As Long
    Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableA")
    Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableB")        

    lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    x = 2
    For r = 2 To lr
        If Range("C" & r).Value = "X" Then 'Evaluate the condition.
            Sh2.Range("B" & x).Value = Sh1.Range("B" & r).Value 'ColumnB
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next r
    Sh2.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you select the sheet?

Comment: First Select is not necessary, but the second is just for show the result.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, SkyMaster. I have a couple questions if you will: I get a run-time (type mismatch) error on lr=Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row; any thoughts on that? Also, is it a problem that I named both the sheets and tables the same thing (i.e. sheet name PARCEL_ATTR_BASE, table name PARCEL_ATTR_base)?

Comment: 1) I have no idea because you have type mismatch error. 2) No problems with the names of the sheets and tables. If you need more help send me the code you're using and some data in your spreadsheet.